# discord.py | how to get list user banned name and id

Tags: discord.py

Discord.py

user banned by me, i want to see a list of banned user and id to remove the ban from user.

`!banlist`
`- for made list of banned user name and id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 0.16.12 you can use [`client.get_bans(serverID)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=ban#discord.Client.get_bans) which returns a list of User objects. You can then iterate through the list and get the id and name from each user. If you wanted to have the bot list the banned users' names and ids, you could do something like:

```
bannnedUsers = await client.get_bans(serverID)
for user in bannedUsers:
    await client.send_message(channelID, user.name + ' ' + user.id)
```

In the rewrite branch it's a little more complicated. You would use [`guild.bans()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html?highlight=banned#discord.Guild.bans) to get a list of tuples with each tuple containing a user object and a string with the reason for the ban. For the same result as before, you would do something like:

```
bans = await guild.bans()
for ban in bans:
    await channel.send(ban[0].name + ' ' + ban[0].id)
```

It should be mentioned that the bot will need the ban_users permission to be able to access these coroutines.

Comment: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'guild' is not defined`
error

Comment: Well, guild needs to be defined if you want to use it. It should be the [guild/server object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#guild). You'll most likely need to get that using ctx.guild

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'guild'

Comment: `@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def banlist(ctx):
    bans = await ctx.guild.bans()
    for ban in bans:
        await channel.send(ban[0].name + ' ' + ban[0].id)`

Comment: You're most likely using discord.py version 0.16.12 and not the rewrite. Try using the first half of my initial message and ignoring the second half. You can check which version you're using by typing ```pip show discord.py``` into the command line

Comment: Additionally, in the block of code you commented, you didn't define ```channel``` when trying to send a message. That would have been a second error. I would strongly recommend familiarizing yourself with the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Version: 0.16.12